# .write выводит только одну строку из переменной

Tags: python

```
with open('separated.txt', 'r') as info:
lines = info.readlines()
print(len(lines))
for line in lines:
    win_id =  line.partition(',')[0]
    win_id = (win_id.partition('ID Win:')[-1])
    print(win_id)
    
with open('pc_build\win_id\win_id.txt', 'w') as winid:
    winid.write(str(win_id))
    winid.write('\n')

winid.close()

info.close()
```

при winid.write(str(win_id)) он выводит только первую строку separated.txt, но print(win_id) выводит весь полученный текст (9 строк)

Comment: 1) отфрорматируйте код. 2) приведите пример(ы) входных и ожидаемых выходных данных

Comment: Только не первую, а последнюю. `print` вы делаете в цикле, а `write` - уже после окончания цикла, с тем, что осталось в переменной на последней его итерации. Поместите `winid.write(str(win_id))` **внутрь цикла** `for line in lines:`, а `with open('pc_build\win_id\win_id.txt', 'w') as winid:` сделайте **перед этим циклом**.

Comment: @CrazyElf спасибо, работает!

Comment: И да, `.close()` не нужно, если вы делаете `with open`